# OUTLOOK is telling me that the contact or group has been deleted, but that group is still in my contacts

Tags: outlook, contacts

I have created a distribution group in OUTLOOk that has been working for many months.  Recently, when I go to use that group or expand the group to remove certain members, OUTLOOK alerts me with the message that "The contact or group has been deleted, and is no longer a valid address book entry," but the thing is, the group is in my address book and has not been deleted.  Am I right to understand that this can happen if a single contact from the list has been deleted from my contacts, thus making this list broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can mean that a contact or a DL included by the group had been deleted. Try to open the DL and open its members one at a time until you get an error.